# Translator Text API | Microsoft Azure | Always ERROR 401000

Tags: azure, php-curl, microsoft-translator, bing-translator-api

I tried to test Microsoft Translator API Text v3.0 but failed with 401 Access denied. I do standard cURL requests (HTTP POST) using PHP 7.3.

```
    $key = "************************";  //  secret key here (from the Azure Portal)
    $host = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com";
    $path = "/translate?api-version=3.0";

    $params = "&to=en&from=bg";

    $text = "За мен лично хора, които задават такива въпроси са несъобразителни.";

    $requestBody = array(
        array(
            'Text' => $text,
        ),
    );

    $content = json_encode($requestBody);

    if (!function_exists('com_create_guid')) {
        function com_create_guid()
        {
            return sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
                mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
                mt_rand(0, 0xffff),
                mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000,
                mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000,
                mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff)
            );
        }
    }

    $curl_headers = array(
        'Content-type: application/json',
        'Content-length: ' . strlen($content),
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ' . $key,
        'X-ClientTraceId: ' . com_create_guid()
    );

    $url = $host . $path . $params;

    $ch = curl_init();
    $curl_content = array('content', $content);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_headers);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
    // Receive server response ...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);


    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //dd(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT));

    if (curl_exec($ch) === false) {
        dd(curl_error($ch));
    }
```

Laravel 5.6, the code is placed on `api.php` route file.

Response Code: 
`"{"error":{"code":401000,"message":"The request is not authorized because credentials are missing or invalid."}}"`

Where is the mistake? Should I enable any settings on the developer portal and so on?

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can help. In the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference) you can find two examples of CURL requests. The difference between the two is that the second one has also the parameter *region*. Only the second request works in my case. Maybe the *region* parameter is essential.

Comment: I can confirm my previous answer. I had the same issue with Python, and once I added *'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region'* to the CURL header, the API worked properly.